# How do I redirect a domain to a specific page using Apache virtual host settings?

Tags: apache, redirect

In my `sites-available` directory, for one of my websites, example1.com I have this setting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

This makes it so that any traffic that goes to example1.com is redirected to example2.com.

However, I would like to set it up so that all traffic that goes to example1.com goes to a specific page on example2.com, such as `example2.com/thisPage`.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/thisPage [R=301]
```

How do I redirect from a domain to a specific page on another domain using Apache configuration settings?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't descibe what your attempt did.  Did you have RewriteEngine ON? Did you have it in the right virtual host? Were there other rules?

You could just use:

```
RedirectMatch .* http://www.example2.com/thisPage
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my question I mention that I have `RewriteEngine On`. I believe I have the correct virtual host, but if you need another specific setting, I will gladly provide it. In any case, I tried the `RedirectMatch` command you suggested, but it does not work. When I go to `example1.com`, I get taken to `example2.com`, but not to `example2.com/thisPage`.